# How to replace the nouns with personal pronouns in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, infinitif

I have a sentence which I have to replace two nouns (which are in bold) with personal pronouns. The sentence is:

> **Le briquet** sert à allumer **les cigarettes**.

I think the answer is:

> Il les sert à allumer.

Am I right or it is the answer incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you analyse this sentence you'll notice that “le briquet” is the subject of “servir” and “les cigarettes” is the (direct) object of “allumer”. All pronouns come before the verb they relate to and the right answer is therefore:

> Il sert à les allumer.